# Forward any route with upper case character to equivalent lowercase route in Kohana 3.3

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

To clarify, I'm doing this for SEO reasons ( avoiding duplicate content ). I don't want site.com/myPage to display site.com/mypage, I want it to forward to the latter.

I've created a small module to forward any route with an uppercase character in it to the equivalent lowercase route. While my solution works, I'm still relatively new to Kohana and curious if there is a better way.
My route in looks like this ( arbirtrary going to 8 assuming none of my urls will be longer than that):

```
Route::set(
    'upper-case-redirect',
    '(<id1>(/<id2>(/<id3>(/<id4>(/<id5>(/<id6>(/<id7>(/<id8>))))))))'
)
->filter(function($route, $params, $request){

        $matched = false;
        $fixed_url = array();
        foreach($params as $index=>$param){
            if(strtolower($index) == 'controller' || strtolower($param) == 'action'){
                continue;
            }
            if($param!==strtolower($param)){
                $matched = true;
                $fixed_url[]= strtolower($param);
            }
        }
        if($matched){
            $params['controller'] =  'RouteCaseFix';
            $params['action'] = 'redirect';
            $params['id1'] = implode("/",$fixed_url);
            return $params;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
})
->defaults(
    array(
        'controller' => 'RouteCaseFix',
        'action' => 'redirect',
    )
);
```

My Controller looks like this
    class Controller_RouteCaseFix extends Controller {

```
    public function action_redirect(){
        $arguments = $this->request->query();
        $url_argument_string = '';
        if(is_array($arguments)){
            $url_argument_string = '?';
            foreach($arguments as $index=>$value){
                $url_argument_string.=$index.'='.$value.'&';                
            }           
        }
        $this->redirect($this->request->param('id1').substr($url_argument_string,0,-1),301);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you want this? Instead of a redirect you could use the `Request::factory()`, This would save you a redirect and the user would never notice anything.

Comment: Added an edit to the original post, that solution would allow duplicate content and potentially dilute SEO value of links to that page when different cases are used.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want any of your routes to be case-sensitive, simply extend the route class:

```
class Route extends Kohana_Route {

    public static function compile($uri, array $regex = NULL)
    {
        return parent::compile($uri, $regex).'i';
    }
}
```